# How to download multiple byte arrays?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorystream

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605510/9587283), we could use something like:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

..to download a file.

In my case, I have to download multiple files.
For example,

```
foreach(int _id in idArray)
{
    byte[] file = //..... generate file using _id
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
    ms.Position = 0;

    return File(ms, "application/pdf", myFileName);
}
```

But this code downloads only the first file.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49974036/1427849), we could generate a zip achieved for multiple files.
But in my scenario, I have to download the files separately.
How should I change my code to download multiple files?

Comment: You are `return`ing in the first iteration, and therefore, the method exits in the first iteration no matter how many items are in the array. Instead, you can add the results to a list and return the list.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, yes, I thought so. How can I add generated files to List and download separately ?? can you provide me with code ??

Comment: You need to learn the basics and try something for yourself. SO is not a coding service

Comment: @JohnB , sure, the example code is what I have tried.

Comment: `?? can you provide me with code ??`

Comment: You need to use separate action methods for each files, and trigger them separately by returning a page containing anchor links which pointed to action methods as mentioned before.

Comment: @JohnB , sure . I mean to modify my code which is work to download the rest files :)